# Search strategy with optional variables

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc, gecode

I'm implementing a simple model in Minizinc to schedule tasks with different priority and duration in a series of time slots, but not all the tasks can be scheduled so some will be left out and I'm trying to maximize the sum of priorities of the scheduled tasks.

I have a working version where the tasks is defined in a array of vars, and non-scheduled tasks have time 0. The constrains have several where clauses to take into account only the scheduled tasks (when[i]>0). The default search strategy is very slow so I changed it to another that worked much better, using Gecode as solver.

Now I'm implementing a different version using optional variables, to get rid off the where clauses, to check if there is any improvement. However, it seems I cannot define a search strategy int_search() when using opt var.

Is there any way to do it?

The working model is as follows (the solve clause with the search strategy I want to try is commented out):

```
int: numtasks=100;
int: numslots=100;

set of int: TASK=1..numtasks;
set of int: SLOT=1..numslots;
array[TASK] of var opt 1..numslots: when;
array[TASK] of int: duration = [(i mod 3)+1 | i in TASK];
array[TASK] of int: prio = [(i mod 10)+1 | i in TASK]; 

include "globals.mzn";
constraint disjunctive(when, duration);

var int: obj = sum(i in TASK where not absent(when[i]))(prio[i]);
%solve ::int_search(when, input_order, indomain_random, complete) maximize obj;
solve maximize obj;

output [show(obj)," ",show(when)];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but can test using "occurs()" inside "int_search", i.e.

```
 solve ::int_search([occurs(when[t]) | t in TASK], input_order, indomain_random, complete) maximize obj;
```

Also, I recommend that you test with some other labelings than input_order/indomain_random, e.g. first_fail/indomain_split etc.

/Hakan

Comment: Thank you. Isee how `occurs` works. Regarding the search strategy, I have tried several combinations but this one seems to be the best to quickly get a solution and improve it. Another search strategy that works fine (that I removed for simplicity) is to provide the array `when` sorted by decreasing priority and using input_order, as it is expected that high-priority tasks are scheduled more often than low-prio. I'm also having issues if I increase the number of tasks and slots (1000, 1000), it crashes or uses all my RAM. I think I'll ask this in a different question.